# 100% stacked area using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frame: LF and HF

```
head(LF)
Year     SS    SS_CQT  SRP  SRP_CQT  TDP  TDP_CQT   TP   TP_CQT
1 2009 386.18 1164.3966 4586 12.30089 5285 14.23955 6707 18.17906
2 2010 268.72  884.9963 4354 13.37728 4927 15.20045 6078 18.81523
3 2011 347.61  746.7686 6924 12.25466 7917 13.84788 9302 16.93291
4 2012 170.68 1218.6758 2471 16.39350 3006 19.60066 3670 24.18561

head(HF)
Year     SS    SS_CQT  SRP  SRP_CQT  TDP  TDP_CQT   TP   TP_CQT
1 2009 184.44  4055.367  535 11.53037  621 13.50632 1175 25.82282
2 2010 118.08  2726.272  737 14.44196  868 16.92781 1236 24.56522
3 2011 119.90  2208.308  663 10.19803  742 11.42253 1086 17.36818
4 2012 554.07 11913.003 2413 45.44719 2781 52.90863 4290 85.87746
5 2013 165.32  5926.628  424 15.93962  461 17.16547  873 31.70556
```

Following relationship follow for above data frame: LF$SS + HF$SS = total load

I want to plot the proportion(%) of LF and HF each column variable using the two data frame as shown below;
[image]

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer doesn't differ much from @missuse's, except that it skips the need to calculate proportions.

For `ggplot`, you generally want data in long shape, so after binding the two data frames and marking which data frame observations come from (creating the `type` column in `mutate`), you should `gather` the data. In `geom_area`, using `position = position_fill()` calculates proportions within each facet, rather than you needing to do this manually.

```r
library(tidyverse)

lf <- read.table(text = "Year     SS    SS_CQT  SRP  SRP_CQT  TDP  TDP_CQT   TP   TP_CQT
1 2009 386.18 1164.3966 4586 12.30089 5285 14.23955 6707 18.17906
2 2010 268.72  884.9963 4354 13.37728 4927 15.20045 6078 18.81523
3 2011 347.61  746.7686 6924 12.25466 7917 13.84788 9302 16.93291
4 2012 170.68 1218.6758 2471 16.39350 3006 19.60066 3670 24.18561", header = T)

hf <- read.table(text = "Year     SS    SS_CQT  SRP  SRP_CQT  TDP  TDP_CQT   TP   TP_CQT
1 2009 184.44  4055.367  535 11.53037  621 13.50632 1175 25.82282
2 2010 118.08  2726.272  737 14.44196  868 16.92781 1236 24.56522
3 2011 119.90  2208.308  663 10.19803  742 11.42253 1086 17.36818
4 2012 554.07 11913.003 2413 45.44719 2781 52.90863 4290 85.87746", header = T)

df <- bind_rows(
  lf %>% mutate(type = "LF"),
  hf %>% mutate(type = "HF")
) %>%
  gather(key = measure, value = value, -Year, -type)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = type)) +
  geom_area(position = position_fill()) +
  facet_wrap(~ measure) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(HF = "darkorange", LF = "slateblue"))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you. The codes are able to display only the blank facets and plots do not get displayed. The same thing happened with the codes suggested by @missuse.

Comment: For being able to debug the issue, it would be more helpful if you post your data with `dput`

Comment: dput(head(df))
    structure(list(Year = c("2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2009", 
    "2010"), type = c("LF", "LF", "LF", "LF", "HF", "HF"), measure = 
    c("SS", 
    "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS"), value = c(755.2682352, 953.55464544, 
    373.46134752, 5870.45817792, 4464.49489344, 2657.7138528)), .Names       = c("Year", 
    "type", "measure", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class =      "data.frame")

Comment: Try converting the years to numeric

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

lf %>%
  mutate(col = "lf") %>% #add column to lf specifying the data frame
  bind_rows(hf %>% #bind rows of hf
              mutate(col = "hf")) %>% #add column to hf specifying the data frame
  gather(key, value, 2:9) %>% #convert to long format
  group_by(key, Year) %>% #group by variable and year
  mutate(ratio = value/sum(value)) %>% #calculate the desired ratio
  ggplot()+
  geom_area(aes(x = Year, y = ratio, fill = col)) + #pretty much self explanatory
    facet_wrap(~key) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

data:

```
lf <- read.table(text = "Year     SS    SS_CQT  SRP  SRP_CQT  TDP  TDP_CQT   TP   TP_CQT
1 2009 386.18 1164.3966 4586 12.30089 5285 14.23955 6707 18.17906
2 2010 268.72  884.9963 4354 13.37728 4927 15.20045 6078 18.81523
3 2011 347.61  746.7686 6924 12.25466 7917 13.84788 9302 16.93291
4 2012 170.68 1218.6758 2471 16.39350 3006 19.60066 3670 24.18561", header = T)

hf <- read.table(text = "Year     SS    SS_CQT  SRP  SRP_CQT  TDP  TDP_CQT   TP   TP_CQT
1 2009 184.44  4055.367  535 11.53037  621 13.50632 1175 25.82282
2 2010 118.08  2726.272  737 14.44196  868 16.92781 1236 24.56522
3 2011 119.90  2208.308  663 10.19803  742 11.42253 1086 17.36818
4 2012 554.07 11913.003 2413 45.44719 2781 52.90863 4290 85.87746", header = T)
```

I have removed the last row from `hf` so it matches the number of rows in `lf`

Comment: Although I used as you suggested, the plots do not appear inside the facets. Only The blank facets are displayed. I do not know, what could be the reason.

Comment: @Vasker Sharma can you reproduce the the full code that I posted starting from the creation of `lf` and `hf`, loading `library(tidyverse)` and then the code `lf %>%....`? Are you able to plat any `ggplot2` example?

Comment: Thank you @missuse, Your approach was a great help. I just converted the year column to numeric and it worked.